# Cocos2D : Stop/Resume CCAction on CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have two CCAnimations running on a CCSprite. How do I check if the specific action is running on a sprite? And how do I pause/resume them as needed?

I have checked the numberOfRunningAction in the actionManager, but it doesn't equal the number I expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to set the tag property of your two actions. Then call getActionByTag, specifying the tag of your desired action. If your result is not nil, the action is running.

Unfortunately, you can't pause any particular action. You can only pause ALL actions (pauseSchedulerAndActions) or stop an individual action (stopActionByTag: or stopAction:), which removes it from the action list. Not what you want.